# Cannot install ruby-sinatra because it relies on virtual package "ruby-rack"

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 11.10, dependencies, ruby

I want to install the package [ruby-sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/) on a Ubuntu 10.11 server. It fails because this package depends on [ruby-rack](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby-rack) -- which is a virtual package. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `rvm` to install and manage your Ruby installations rather than apt-get. It makes it much more flexible, you can have multiple Ruby installations at the same time then flick between them with one command.

See their page: http://beginrescueend.com/